# How to represent custom Java classes in a XML schema?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have a Java class for which I want to create an XML schema -

```
class Person {
   String name;
   Locale locale;
}
```

The name element can be defined as `xsd:string` type and mapping using JAXB is straightforward.

What is the good approach to represent the `Locale` class and how do I map it using JAXB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JAXB `XmlAdapter` To convert an unmappable class into a mappable one for the purposes of marshalling/unmarshalling.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

The only state that you need to persist from `Locale` are the language, country and variant.

```
<locale>
  <language>en</language>
  <country>US</country>
  <variant/>
</locale>
```